# Microsoft Bot deployed to Azure isn't working

Tags: botframework

I have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=multitenant%2Cnewgroup%2Cjavascript) tutorial to publish a Microsoft Bot to Azure. I got a message that the bot was deployed successfully and got a messaging endpoint that's a public domain: [image] When trying to test the bot in web chat, it appears to connect, however typing something doesn't get any response: [image] It's supposed to be the basic echo bot. When testing locally using the bot framework emulator it was working and I haven't changed any of the code since deploying. When trying to go to the messaging endpoint I get this: [image] When I try to go the the same URL but with /api/messages removed I get this: [image] Any help would be appreciated! As an update there are 'issues' listed in the channels blade of my bot, although they don't have an error code. I'm not sure where to go from here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOhKV.png)[image]

Comment: Did you make sure to fill in the app settings/env/etc. file with the appid, password, and other required info? Did you make sure all the required resources are running? Any error messages across your Azure resources?

Comment: look like you configured the bot project settings but the project(code) is not published. Are you using Bot composer or Bot Framework?

Comment: @VinothRajendran I am using the Bot Framework and the SDK. I don't know what you mean by the code isn't published. Could you specify what that means?

Comment: @AP01 I do have the correct appid and password etc in .env, however I'm not sure what app settings are. I'm also not sure what it means for all the required resources to be running. I looked into error logging a little bit but it seemed to require a lot of steps so I don't currently have error logging set up.

Comment: In the Azure Bot resource, go to the channels blade and see if there are any red "Issues" warnings. At this point, we don't have enough info to know where you might have gone wrong in the deployment process. You might consider sharing more info about what exactly you did.

Comment: @AP01 I have updated my post showing what the error messages on my channels blade shows.